# applyLinearImpulse not working (Box2d)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I have an object that uses the same physics as in billiards. Here's the full code:

```
    BodyDef bddDef = new BodyDef();
    bddDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bddDef.position.x = Position.x;
    bddDef.position.y = Position.y;

    bddDef.linearDamping = .03f;
    bddDef.angularDamping = .09f;
    bddDef.gravityScale = 10F;

    bdBox = wWorld.createBody(bddDef);

    CircleShape csCircle = new CircleShape();

    csCircle.setRadius(this.SIZE_RADIUS);
    csCircle.getPosition().x = bddDef.position.x;
    csCircle.getPosition().y = bddDef.position.y;

    FixtureDef fxtDef = new FixtureDef();
    fxtDef.density = 20.00f; 
    fxtDef.friction = 0f;
    fxtDef.restitution = 0.3f;
    fxtDef.shape = csCircle;

    bdBox.setBullet(true);

    bdBox.resetMassData();

    this.fxtSensorFixture = bdBox.createFixture(fxtDef);
    csCircle.dispose();
```

Set applyLinearImpulse like this

```
public void update(float x, float y){
    if(distance(x,y)<=SIZE_RADIUS)
        return;
    Vector2 vec =  new Vector2(x,y);
    getBody().applyLinearImpulse(this.localToStageCoordinates(vec), getBody().getPosition(), true);
}
```

but the object is not moving or is moving at a very slow rate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Not moving" and "moving at a slow rate" are two whole different things. If it is not moving, you probably fail somewhere totally in your code, but if it moves slowly, you probably have some calculation issues which are probably minor. So, is it moving slowly or does not move at all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm sorry, did not correctly put. Of course we are talking about a very small speed.

Comment: Ok, I think you have something wrong with your calculations. Check what is sent to applyLinearImpulse method. You also may have something wrong with your update game logic (refresh rate etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I look at the coordinates of the points before sending a method applyLinearImpulse, then visually they have the correct coordinates. The game world is updated here so getWorld().step(delta, 4, 4) in the render method of the current activity. What else could I leave out?

Comment: Another small clarification. I did not ask additional speed. Specify only applyLinearImpulse.

Comment: It is better to post your solution as an answer and accept it. It will  mark question as solved, making it clear to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is found. If anyone faced with the same problem, you can try

```
    public void update(float x, float y){
    Vector2 pos = bdBox.getPosition();
    bdBox.applyLinearImpulse(x*bdBox.getMass(), y*bdBox.getMass(), pos.x, pos.y, true);
}
```